# Using GoogleAnalytics with a Service Account

Tags: google-analytics-api, service-accounts

I'm trying to use the [Google.Apis.Analytics.v3](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Analytics.v3/) client Library to retrieve metrics and I would like to work with a [Service Account](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtAuthorization).

According to the documentation and several questions here on StackOverflow, I assume this should work. I have already used Service Accounts in the past against the Google BigQuery and Google Cloud Storage APIs, so I thought I could make it to work quite easily.

Unfortunately, each time I perform an operation against Google Analytics, I receive the following error:

`TokenResponseException:`
Additional information: Error:"invalid_grant", Description:"", Uri:""

For the record, here what I have done:

- Created a brand new project in Google Developer Console.
- Enabled Google Analytics API.
- Create a "Service Account" Client ID.
- Take note the "Client ID" the certificate and its password.
- Add the Service Account "Email address" as a user with full permission on Google Analytics Account.

Here is the code I'm using to connect to Google Analytics:

```cs
private static AnalyticsService ConnectServiceAccount()
{
    const string serviceAccountId = "xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com";
    const string serviceAccountCertificate = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-privatekey.p12";
    const string applicationName = "";

    var certificate = GetServiceAccountCertificate(serviceAccountCertificate);
    var credentials = new ServiceAccountCredential(new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountId)
    {
        Scopes = new[] {
            AnalyticsService.Scope.Analytics,
            AnalyticsService.Scope.AnalyticsEdit,
            AnalyticsService.Scope.AnalyticsManageUsers,
            AnalyticsService.Scope.AnalyticsProvision,
            AnalyticsService.Scope.AnalyticsReadonly
        },
    }.FromCertificate(certificate)
        );

    var service =
        new AnalyticsService(
            new BaseClientService.Initializer
            {
                GZipEnabled = true,
                HttpClientInitializer = credentials,
            });
    return service;
}
```

Can someone help me troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: I have asked the same question but for php...

Comment: Waiting for an answer...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24572077/google-service-account-example-returns-error-refreshing-the-oauth2-token-err

Comment: add the service account email address as a user in Google Analytics at the Account level.  It cant be just added at the profile level.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24572077/google-service-account-example-returns-error-refreshing-the-oauth2-token-err)

The service account is an email address which is like **@developer.gserviceaccount.com**

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using the wrong `serviceAccountID`. It should be the one ending in `@developer.gserviceaccount.com`

And, you only need to give that email `Read and Analyze` rights not full control in your analytics account.

I also thought it needed an `applicationName`. This is the app name in your GA console.